# Permissions Report

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, reporting

Is there anyway to export a report that shows all permissions in the tenant? We are specifically looking for places that inheritance is broken and external sharing invites that have been sent.

Powershell, CSOM, Admin & 3rd party tools are welcome answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer to the following article:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-c9ec4f64

Comment: You can also refer to the methods provided in this article:    https://sharegate.com/blog/build-the-perfect-sharepoint-security-report

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to answer to ([Report for Permissions Groups and Users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265251/report-for-permissions-groups-and-users/265275#265275)) The script I posted there is exactly what you are looking for just give the 'https://yourcompany.sharepoint.com'as starting point

Comment: Is it mainly for subsites though? We don't use them and are more interested in Doc Libs and external sharing links

Comment: if you want to get a report On Document Library You can modify That code. That code is a good start point