# Listing groups with the users in them using PowerShell - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, groups

Is it possible to list all groups on the SPO website along with the users who belong to a given group and export the results to Excel?

I would like to add that 2FA is enabled on the website.

Unless there is an easier way than PowerShell.

I want to have a permissions matrix for a given site.

Comment: Try take a look on this answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265251/report-for-permissions-groups-and-users/265275#265275

Answer (score 0):

Please try this powershell:

```
#Admin Center & Site collection URL
$AdminCenterURL = "https://Crescent-admin.sharepoint.com/"
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\GroupsReport.csv"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
 
$GroupsData = @()
 
#Get all Site collections
Get-SPOSite -Limit ALL | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host -f Yellow "Processing Site Collection:"$_.URL
  
    #get sharepoint online groups powershell
    $SiteGroups = Get-SPOSiteGroup -Site $_.URL
 
    Write-host "Total Number of Groups Found:"$SiteGroups.Count
 
    ForEach($Group in $SiteGroups)
    {
        $GroupsData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            'Site URL' = $_.URL
            'Group Name' = $Group.Title
            'Permissions' = $Group.Roles -join ","
            'Users' =  $Group.Users -join ","
        }
    }
}
#Export the data to CSV
$GroupsData | Export-Csv $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
 
Write-host -f Green "Groups Report Generated Successfully!"
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Site Users and Groups Report using PowerShell](https://%20https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/06/sharepoint-online-site-users-and-groups-report-powershell.html)